# Dynamic Highcharts is not updating

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my use case. I am using Flume and Spark Streaming to count the number of events generated from the server. So in the output of the spark i get timestamp and number of events. After every 10 second the old value is erased and new value is written in a file in HDFS.

I have created Spring framework which will pull the data from HDFS convert it to json and push it to Highcharts. So I am trying to generate a live spline chart which will show timestamp in the x-axis and number of count in the y-axis and update it as it gets new data from the spark output after every 10 seconds. But the x-axis is not shifting and I can see 10 zero values in y-axis. So I am unable to get the updated y value. I am sure I am missing something in the java script. Because from the console of the spring i can see the events are updating after every 10 seconds. But its not reflecting in the chart.

I am stuck here for past two weeks and desperately need help. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/appStart.js" ></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div  class="chart" id="statusChart" >
        </div> 
    </body>

    $(function() {

        var url = 'statistics';

        $.ajax(url).done(function(data) {
            loadStatusChart(data);
        });

    });

    function updateStatusSeries(series){
        var url = 'statistics';

        $.ajax(url).done(function(data) {
            var statusCode = data.statusCode[0];
            series.addPoint([statusCode.label, statusCode.value], true, true);
        });
    }

    function loadStatusChart(statistics) {
        var StatusCode = statistics.statusCode;

        var StatusSeries = [];
        $.each(StatusCode, function(index, item) {

            var timeInSeconds = item.label/1000;
            for(var i = 10; i >= 1; i--){
                StatusSeries.push({
                    x : (timeInSeconds - (i*10))*1000,
                    y : 0
                });
            }
            StatusSeries.push({
                x : item.label,
                y : item.value
            });
        })
        var x = StatusCode.length;

        $("#statusChart").highcharts({
            chart : {
                type : 'spline',
                //animation : Highcharts.svg,
                marginRight : 10,
                events : {
                    load : function(){
                        //set up updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function (){
                            updateStatusSeries(series);
                        }, 10000);
                    }
                }         
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Counts'
                },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{ data: StatusSeries }]
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're getting leading zeroes in the chart because of this code:

```
for(var i = 10; i >= 1; i--){  // <----- 10
    StatusSeries.push({
        x : (timeInSeconds - (i*10))*1000,
        y : 0  // <----- zero values
    });
}
```

Second, your chart isn't advancing because in this part

```
events : {
    load : function(){
        //set up updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function (){
            updateStatusSeries(series); // <----- Not updating series
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

`updateStatusSeries(series)` actually doesn't update `series`, thus the chart doesn't get new data and simply stays on the same spot.

To fix that you can either

- create a global `chart` object and use it to access its series, like described here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data
- modify your `updateStatusSeries()` so that it uses a callback passed to it, like shown here: http://www.in-example.com/?p=316

Also, date formatting (in `tooltip.formatter`) should be done like so:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Dekkard. My code followed the similar procedure. I have found the solution. The x-axis was not moving because I was passing a string there. But when I switched with number it started moving [x : Number(item.label)] . And in the y-axis I just need to put NULL instead of zero. So It is not showing any leading zeros anymore.